# Generalized induction proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove using general induction that:

$$\forall m\geq 0\,\,\,\,\,\ \forall l\geq m+1:\qquad f_l=f_{m+1}*f_{l-m}+f_m*f_{l-(m+1)}, \qquad\qquad (1)$$
where $f_l$ is the $l$-th Fibonacci number, where $f_0=0$, $f_1=1$, etc.

[My solution for question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC25x.png)

I couldn't understand how to determine which condition to apply l+1 or m+1 in second induction step

Comment: Please, try to edit your question so as to actually contain the problem itself, rather than linking to an image of the problem; same goes for your solution.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to edit the image.